# Entity Framework major performance issue when deploy to Azure

Tags: entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

We've got an ASP.NET Web API application and we are using Entity Framework v6.1.3 and SQL Server 2012. Everything works fine locally with no performance issues, it also works very well on a server we have that runs Windows Server 2012.

When we tried Azure as a cloud platform, we got the free trial and deployed our application, but the performance was so bad with some queries taking from 4-7 minutes. Also as a side note, the server we got is connected to the internet and can be accessed outside our company's internal network, the performance still is not an issue only on Azure we faced this problem.

Any help would be appreciated, we want to invest in Azure but we fear we will face same issues we had on our trial subscription.

Comment: Are your web server and sql server instance in same region? If they are, you should definitely write to azure customer services with this question.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using Basic tier which has 5 DTUs. Simply, we can say this database can process 5 transactions per second. Azure have tiers from basic to P11 which is 5 DTUs to 1750 DTUs. Additionally, if you choose right region for data center, it will help for network speed.

Select [single database on menu](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/?b=16.50) and see the tiers and their prices. You can see how many DTUs you are using on portal. That's way you can choose perfect price/perfomance tier for you. For example, If it's higher than 80% increase the tier. If it's below 60% you can keep this tier.